# Using a verb as subject of a sentence

Tags: word-choice, gerunds, infinitives, infinitive-vs-gerund

In Italian, when I write a sentence about an action (e.g. *eating fish*, *playing*), I would use the **infinitive**, such as  *mangiare pesce fa bene alla salute* (which literally is "to eat fish is healthy"), or *giocare aiuta ad imparare* (which literally is "to play helps to learn").

I would use the **gerund** in *giocando si impara*, but that would roughly mean "When playing, you learn." and in this case the infinitive would not be correct. (*Giocare si impara* is not what you would say in Italian.)

Should I use the infinitive, or the gerund, in sentences similar to the following ones?

- To play with fire is dangerous.
- To win the lottery is just a matter of luck.
- To escape from Alcatraz is impossible.
- To practice makes you perfect.

Is the infinitive always wrong, when the verb is the subject of a sentence?

Comment: Note that the last example sounds better as the popular idiomatic expression "Practice makes perfect."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In terms of grammar, either form is perfectly acceptable. The preferred usage will certainly vary by region, but in my personal experience, the gerund is definitely the more common form, whereas the infinitive can often sound dated and awkward. However, I have certainly heard the infinitive used well, especially in more formal contexts.